# Bing maps doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox 26

Tags: firefox, bing-maps

On Mozilla Firefox version 26 bing maps doesn't work. I dosn't zoom and locate (and location service are enabled in firefox settings). In don't get any error or warning. In all other browsers (IE, Chrome...) all works fine. Where is problem?

Comment: How is this related to programming?
Stackoverflow is a site where you can ask questions related to programming!

Comment: So if I develop application with Bing Maps and if that Bing Maps in some situation in my application doesn't work I would first check my code to see if I'm doing something wrong or if is some other nature of problem. So I think it's a question regarding programming. I believe that here is at least few programmers who come in contact or developed Bing maps or something regarding them and I believe that they can help me at least to tell that this is not problem with coding. If I'm wrong I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with Firefox 26 according to the [supported browser information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427618.aspx).

> Firefox 3.6 and later

It works fine when I run it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetLocation() {
if (!!navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(UpdateLocation, HandleErrors);
}
}

function UpdateLocation(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

setPushpin(longitude, latitude);
document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', changePosition);
}

function HandleErrors(error) {
switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
        break;
    default: alert("unknown error");
        break;
}  
}

function setPushpin(longi, lati){
map.setView({ center: { latitude: lati, longitude: longi }, zoom: 16});
deletePushpin();
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {icon:newURL+"images/marker.png", height:35, width:26}); 
map.entities.push(pushpin); 
pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lati, longi));
}

function deletePushpin(){
for(var i=map.entities.getLength()-1;i>=0;i--){
    var pushpin= map.entities.get(i); 
    if (pushpin instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin){ 
        map.entities.removeAt(i);  
    }
} 
}

changePosition = function (e) {
if (e.targetType == "map") {
    var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    var loc = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point);

    document.getElementById('longitude').value = loc.longitude;
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = loc.latitude;

    setPushpin(loc.longitude, loc.latitude);
}
 }
```

So this is my code for getting current locations and put pushpin on it.

I don't get any error. Map isn't doing anything just stays on full world view.

On all other browsers works just fine, it zooms, get current location and put pushpin on it.

This is where I call map:

```
 map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('placeForMap'), {credentials:"xxx",showMapTypeSelector:false, disableBirdseye: true});
GetLocation();
```

I tried to use Bing Ajax 7 controls, but same problem is there too, bing map in firefox is drop dead, and in other browser works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the Bing Maps control. Firefox 26 has a couple of bugs in it which are causing the issue you are encountering.